# createtextrange in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I need a little help in creating a textrange in IE 11. In previous IE have this bit of code

```
var theSelection  = document.selection.createRange();
--Code that works on a text range because create range returns a text range
```

I understand that IE11 no longer support [selection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx) and we have to use [getSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975169(v=vs.85).aspx). So now my new code looks like this

```
var theSelection  = document.getSelection().createRange();
--Code that works on a text range because create range returns a text range
```

The problem that I am having is that I keep getting this error where it says that object does not support method or property createRange. I have also tried it like this, which gives me the same error.

```
 var theSelection  = document.getSelection().toString().createRange();
--Code that works on a text range because create range returns a text range
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `document.body.createTextRange()` instead.

Comment: @PHPglue that works but it does not allow me to get the selected text.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I believe you have what you need ...

`document.selection.createRange()` is replaced with `document.getSelection()` ...

There is also a note **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx)** that ...

`document.selection` is replaced with `window.getSelection` ...

Comment: I checked and when I do a `console.log(document.getSelection())` I am getting a selection object returned instead of a text range object. Also when I try to execute the find function it says that the property or method is not supported.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535872(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Are you looking for the findText method? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536422(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @LanceLeonard I am actually already using the the `findText` method. But in order for me to call thet method I need to create a textrange from the new `getSelection` function which is where I am having trouble.